# SMB service is running on port 445 / Why / What process

Tags: linux, samba, server-message-block, debian-wheezy

I am currently trying to 'harden' all my servers, starting by turning of all services I dont need.

This one is a nginx reverse proxy and metasploit says
smb 445 tcp filtered
http://gyazo.com/6adcdcf4982801f481b8338d913545bb

But I cant find any service running on this port:
service --status-all

```
 [ + ]  bind9
 [ - ]  bootlogs
 [ ? ]  bootmisc.sh
 [ ? ]  checkfs.sh
 [ ? ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh
 [ - ]  checkroot.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  fail2ban
 [ - ]  fetchmail
 [ - ]  hostname.sh
 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  kbd
 [ - ]  keymap.sh
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  modules_dep.sh
 [ - ]  motd
 [ ? ]  mountall-bootclean.sh
 [ ? ]  mountall.sh
 [ ? ]  mountdevsubfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mountkernfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mountnfs-bootclean.sh
 [ ? ]  mountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  mtab.sh
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ + ]  nginx
 [ ? ]  plymouth
 [ ? ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  procps
 [ - ]  quota
 [ - ]  quotarpc
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ - ]  rmnologin
 [ - ]  rpcbind
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  saslauthd
 [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
 [ + ]  sendmail
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ - ]  sudo
 [ - ]  udev
 [ ? ]  udev-mtab
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ - ]  urandom
 [ - ]  wide-dhcpv6-client
 [ ? ]  xinetd
```

Can anyone please point me in the correct direction.

Samba is completely removed (apt-get purge samba*), so not sure why it would still have port 445 open.

Pretty sure that is a very basic question, but my research just didn't come up with anything.

Thank you

netstat -lnp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 LOCALHOST:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1586/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1586/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1586/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1722/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1586/named      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8772/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:PORT            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1763/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1722/sendmail: MTA:
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1586/named      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1586/named      
tcp6       0      0 :::PORT                 :::*                    LISTEN      1763/sshd       
udp        0      0 LOCALHOST:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1586/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1586/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1586/named      
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                1586/named      
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3750021142 1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3750023597 1662/saslauthd      /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     3750021553 101/udevd           /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3820548573 6223/python         /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3820548623 6225/gam_server     @/tmp/fam-root-
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3750023674 1722/sendmail: MTA: /var/run/sendmail/mta/smcontrol
```

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -lnp`?

Comment: added the output

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly took the output from another server. It is fixed now, but are verified from the nginx reverse proxy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"smb 445 tcp filtered" does **not** means that something is listening on port 445. From nmap man page:

> Filtered. means that a firewall, filter, or other network obstacle is blocking the port so that Nmap cannot tell whether it is open or closed